# Removing Port number from nginx running on non standard port

Tags: nginx, proxy, reverse-proxy

I have an nginx server running on port 9094, and it listens to a server name which is mapped to localhost in the `etc/hosts` file.

```
server {
        listen 9094;
        listen [::]:9094;
        server_name www.myserver.local;
        port_in_redirect off;
        server_name_in_redirect off;

        proxy_set_header Host $host:$server_port;

        location /portal/foreman/ {
                rewrite ^/portal/foreman(.*)$ $1 break;
                proxy_pass http://localhost:3001;
                proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        }

        location /api/ {
                rewrite ^/api(.*)$ $1 break;
                proxy_pass  http://127.0.0.1:8080;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        }

        location /login {
                rewrite ^/login(.*)/$ /$1 permanent;
                proxy_pass http://localhost:3000;
                proxy_redirect off;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        }
}
```

In my `/etc/hosts` file i have the following entry

```
127.0.0.1  www.myserver.local
```

When i enter `www.myserver.local:9094` everything works as usual, with the redirection. Can someone help me with a way i can remove the port number and the thing still works eg: www.myserver.local/login will redirect me directly to my login page..

when i run www.myserver.local in my browser, the browser gives an error saying, refused to connect

Comment: The browser is trying to connect to port 80 or 443. To use a non-standard port, you need to specify the port number in the URL. To use a URL without a port number, the server must be listening on a standard port (80 or 443).

Comment: Thanks yea.. figured that out with some reading.. thanks..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A browser uses one of these three ports.

1. 80 (HTTP)
2. 443 (HTTPS) or
3. 8080 (HTTP Alternate)

So if you want to visit a non standard port from a browser, you need to specify the port in the url. It won't work otherwise.

Answer (score 2):

You have to change your config to listen on port 80 and the restart nginx. The config should look as below

```
server {
        listen 80;
        listen [::]:80;
```

use `netstat -tulpn | grep 80` to ensure the server is listening on this port